# Connection between Lindhard susceptibility and Free energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, fermions

I've encoutered a few times, but I never got an explanation for it... How is the **spin-dependent** Lindhard function for the dynamical susceptibility of an electron gas
$$
\chi_{\sigma,\sigma'} (q, \omega) \propto \sum_k \frac{\langle n_{k,\sigma} \rangle - \langle n_{k+q,\sigma'} \rangle }{\epsilon_{k,\sigma} - \epsilon_{k+q,\sigma'} - \hbar \omega} \ ,
$$
(with the kinetic energy $\epsilon_k$, spin $\sigma$) related to the susceptibilities derived from the Free energy? For example, I've found the relation for the static limit of the susceptibility perpendicular to the ordered moment (or generally on order parameter) $\vec m$
$$
\chi_\perp(0, 0) = \frac{1}{m} \frac{\partial F}{\partial m} = \frac 12 \left(\chi_{\uparrow,\downarrow}(0,0) + \chi_{\downarrow,\uparrow}(0,0) \right)
$$
but I couldn't find the relation between $\chi_\parallel(0, 0) = \partial_m^2 F / \partial m^2$ and $\chi_{\sigma,\sigma}(0,0)$ ($m$ is the magnetude of $\vec m$). Even worse, I never found an explanation for these relations.

Any ideas?